# Request for Clarification : Differentiability vs Analytic

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the function $f(x)=e^{-1/x}$ if $x>0$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise, now previously I managed to show that $f$ is infinitely differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$ so that includes differentiable at $x>0$, $x<0$, and the most important one $x=0$. The problem lies with showing that $f$ is not analytic at $x=0$ this confuses me since I have shown that $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$. How could this be interpreted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look back at the definition of analyticity. It doesn't just say that all of the derivatives of $f$ exist, it says that "Taylor series work well" for $f$:

> $f$ is analytic iff for each $a$, the Taylor series $T^f_a$ agrees with $f$ around $a$ - that is, there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that $T_a^f$ is defined and equals $f$ on the interval $(a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon).$

Intuitively, analyticity doesn't just say that all the derivatives of $f$ exist at each point, but that the various derivatives contain "all the information about $f$:" there's no point where knowing the derivatives of $f$ won't let you figure out what $f$ is, at least "locally."

So to show that your $f$ is **not** analytic, what you want to do is find some point where the Taylor series for $f$ "goes wrong" somehow. Now your $f$ consists of three regions: negative $x$, positive $x$, and $x=0$ where the first two regions meet. On each of the first two regions $f$ is very "tame:" $f$ is equal to some function we already know to be analytic. So the only possible "weird point" for $f$ is $a=0$. You know that $f$ is infinitely differentiable here too, but again analyticity is more than just infinite differentiability:

> What is $T_0^f$? Does this "look like $f$" even in a small neighborhood of $0$?

What we'll see is that, while the infinite differentiability of $f$ at $0$ does allow us to build the series $T_0^f$, somehow information is lost when we do so.

Comment: Thank you for your lengthy answer, I note that indeed at $x=0$ the taylor series does not exist yet as you stated that the infinite differentiability of $f$ at $0$ does exist however it is came to my notice now that a function being analytic is not that attached to $f$ being differentiable. Can you rephrase what you mean by information is lost? do you refer that just the fact that the taylor series at $0$ doesn't exist then $f$ can not be analytic?

Comment: I recall a theorem due to Spivak, If $f$ is differentiable at $c$ and $\lim_{x\to c}=L$, then $f'(c)=L$. so would this not show that $f^{(n)}(0)=0$?

Comment: @Kamola I'm not sure what you mean. The Taylor series **does** exist - or at least we can consider an infinite series made up from the various derivatives of $f$. That's what I mean by $T_a^f$.

Comment: But you claim that in order to have $f$ being not analytic at $x=0$, it is necessary to show that at $x=0$, the taylor series of $f$ goes terribly wrong. @Noah Schweber

Comment: @Kamola I do indeed, but I'm not referring to the Taylor series on its own: I'm referring to the Taylor series' **relationship with $f$**. Try computing $T_0^f$, that is, the series $$f(0)+\sum_{i=1}^\infty {f^{(i)}(0)\over i!}x.$$ Do you see why this doesn't behave at all like $f$? (Your earlier comment re: Spivak, albeit incomplete, will be useful here.)

Comment: Ahh, now I understand the relationship it all now make sense, by the way I believe you forgot to add the exponent for $x$. Thank you for your help sir!

Comment: @Kamola Whoops, I most definitely did! It's too late to edit that comment though. Glad I could help!